# gemfire client get pool is null .gemfire9.0

Tags: java, xml, spring, pool, gemfire

xml:

```
<gfe:client-cache id="gemfireCache" pool-name="gemfirePool"/>


<gfe:pool id="gemfirePool"  max-connections="1000" server-group="datastore" read-timeout="60000" 
 subscription-enabled="true" pr-single-hop-enabled="false"  >
     <gfe:locator host="host" port="12345" />
</gfe:pool>
```

java:

```
     Pool clientPool=PoolManager.find("gemfirePool");
    Map<String,Pool> mapPool=PoolManager.getAll();
    System.out.println("clientPool:"+clientPool);
    System.out.println("mapPool:"+mapPool);
```

clientPool is null and mapPool is null,too.

why??
please

Answer (score 1):

You should **stick to one single approach**: either use pure [GemFire API](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/gemfire/about_gemfire.html) or pure [spring-data-gemfire API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/), not both at the same time because some incompatibilities may arise, like this one.

That said, my guess (haven't tested) is that somehow the `PoolManager` ([GemFire](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/) class) can't access the pools instantiated by the `PoolFactoryBean` ([spring-data-gemfire](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/) class).

If you're configuring your cache through [spring-data-gemfire](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/) and you want to access the `Pool` instance, you need to do so through one of the different spring container mechanisms: `@Autowire`, `applicationContext.getBean(Pool.class)`, etc.

Cheers!.

Comment: Thank you !! It helps me a lot.  1.But，In gemfire6.6.3 and spring-data-gemfire1.3.0, The  PoolManager.getAll() is not null .It is running.

Comment: Wow, those are **really old versions**!!... I'd suggest upgrading your libraries to the latest available releases, it seems that tons of bugs have been fixed since GemFire 6.6.3 and spring-data-gemfire 1.3.0. Also, you might want to have a look at [Spring Data GemFire to GemFire Version Compatibility](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-GemFire-to-GemFire-Version-Compatibility), your current combination doesn't seem to be supported. Cheers!.

Comment: Thanks,Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks. applicationContext.getBean(Pool.class) .It is available